# CSS: Style for a breadcrumb (very specific)

Tags: css

I'm running around in circles with a CSS task, so allow me to ask for help for this very specific problem.

There's a HTML breadcrumb coming out of a CMS (i.e. an external system, that I cannot change), which I would like to style.

It should look like this:

**T1 BOLD** > **T2 BOLD** when it's last, NORMAL when it's not last > T3 NORMAL if it exists

So the breadcrumb can be 2 elements or 3, but the last element must always have font-weight: normal.

The HTML looks like this (beware: unfortunately I CANNOT change this weird HTML):

```
<div class="breadcrumb">
    <span> 
        <a href="#"> 
            <span>T1 bold</span>
        </a> ›
    </span> 
    <a href="/"> 
        <span>T2 should be bold, because it's not last</span>
    </a> › 
    <span>T3 normal</span>
</div>

<div class="breadcrumb">
    <span> 
        <a href="#"> 
            <span>T1 bold</span>
        </a> ›
    </span> 
    <a href="/">
        <span>T2 should be normal, because it's last</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

I tried this CSS, but it doesn't work the way I want it to.

```
.breadcrumb>span:last-child, #breadcrumb>a:last-child {
    font-weight: normal !important;
}

.breadcrumb>a span {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

The JSFiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/uk4q2cvu/

The question is: what css will cause all items in the breadcrumb to be bold, except the last item - which should be font-weight normal

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks
Bernhard

Comment: I'm having a really hard time understanding what the question is.

Comment: The question is: what css will cause all items in the breadcrumb to be bold, except the last item - which should be font-weight normal

Comment: j08691 and cale_b: I've updated the post with the explicit question. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5L192vq7/1/)

`:last-child` gets the job done, regardless of whether it's a span or an a:

```
.breadcrumb > * {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.breadcrumb > *:last-child {
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Comment: Wonderful, it works. Thank you!

I was toying quite a lot with last-child, but didn't have *:last-child in my mind. Great.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a clean update of your example:

```css
.breadcrumb {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.breadcrumb > li {
  display: inline;
}

.breadcrumb > li:not(:last-child) {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.breadcrumb > li:not(:last-child):after {
  content: " › ";
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<ul class="breadcrumb">
  <li><a href="#">T1 Bold</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">T2 Bold</a></li>
  <li>T3 Normal</li>
</ul>

<ul class="breadcrumb">
  <li><a href="#">T1 Bold</a></li>
  <li>T2 Normal</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: "beware: unfortunately I CANNOT change this weird HTML" - OP

Comment: somehow skipped that part, sorry.

Comment: Still upvoted because this is a good way to accomplish this same end.

Comment: Yes, looks much nicer like that.

Answer (score 0):

Two straightforward rules:

```
.breadcrumb a {
font-weight: bold;
}

.breadcrumb a:last-of-type {
font-weight: normal;
}
```

The first rule bolds all .breadcrumb anchors.

The second rule unbolds the last anchor in each .breadcrumb series.

## =====

Even better, here's a single rule which achieves the same result:

```
.breadcrumb a:nth-of-type(n-1) {
font-weight: bold;
}
```